# What is the scope of research in the field of Compiler Design and Construction?

Tags: compiler-construction

I am studying the basics of Compiler Design in this semester. I really like the subject and want to pursue it further.
My aim is to do Masters in Computer Science, so I wanted to know about the prospective areas which one can research in, in the field of Compilers...

Comment: Brace yourselves! Close-voters are coming! :P

Comment: Step one: learn what's already out there by reading papers, which are trivially searched for. Part of doing research is learning how to do research-and this one is really easy to do on your own.

Comment: P.S. This question _might_ be a better fit at http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: There is a lot of work currently going on in partial specialisation and in certified compilers, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about compiler design, but I do use them a lot. :) And areas in which compilers can continuously improve include:

- Automatic code optimization (speed, size, memory use, whatever);
- Optimization of the compiler itself
- Various strategies for finding bugs (and suspicious places) in code.

Other interesting (albeit more theoretical than practical) uses might include:

- Generating corruption-resilient code (both hardware/software problems that result in corrupted memory). Or perhaps code that fails-fast in such cases. This could be useful in space probes. Of course it wouldn't be possible to catch "everything", but some classes of errors could be detectable.
- "Forgiving" compilers which fix typos (albeit with a warning). Controversial, I agree, but maybe could have some uses in education.
- Following that thought, if there are such "forgivable" features in a language (like semicolons), then it could be argued that it's boilerplate and programmers should not be forced to write it when the compiler can just infer whatever it needs automatically. So maybe you can design a language (and the compiler for it) which does not have such "boilerplate requirements".

Comment: Ahh, a minus vote. Fair enough. Could I please get an explanation what for?